# Building query tool for spatialite data in QGIS?

Tags: spatialite, qgis-2, query, tools

I am trying to build some tool for a collegue of mine to query data from a spatialite database while clicking on vector features.

My first guess is, that I could do this with an "action" I define for the layer. The example actions provided for layers unfortunately do not give me any hint how to perform, and more detailed documentation on actions is quite absent.

I need a query, cause each feature in layer has many corresponding entries in the database table (one-to-many).

While performing the action, I would like to pop up simple table which lists the corresponding data sharing the same id as the feature.

In the example action, i can query an attribute of the layer with this:

```
echo "[% "id" %]"
```

which then looks like this:
[image]

Ok, that's a start.

But what i need is a table which lists all items in a spatialite table with the same id-attribute as the feature.

My data structure:

```
Layer attribute: 
id

Data table: 
id | name | year
```

The layer itself is stored in the spatialite database too, if thats of any help.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I do this with:

echo    [% "id" %],"  [% "name" %],   [% "year" %]

**OBSERVATION**:

- If you have two or more point in the same local, you will get only one response.

I need the next response, if someone knows how to do:

```
id  name   year     (for point 3) 
id  name   year     (for point 3)    
id  name   year     (for point 3)
```

example:

```
17   Elsa   1985    
17   Ana    1991    
17   Olaf   2011
```